# How to send a whatsapp message from python

Tags: python-3.x, api, frameworks, message, whatsapp

I am trying to create a program which on certain conditions will send whatsapp message as notification. I want to perform this task without any third-party registration. Is there a way I can perform this using any python module or framework ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file called "wasend.py" and write the following code on it:

```
import webbrowser
import pyautogui
from time import sleep

def send(text, phone):
    webbrowser.open("whatsapp://send?text=" + text.replace('\n', '%0A') + "&phone=" + phone.replace('+', ''))
    sleep(10)
    pyautogui.click(x=1787, y=978)
    sleep(0.2)
    pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
    sleep(1)
    pyautogui.hotkey('alt', "f4")
```

Then, execute the following commands:

```
$ pip install pyautogui
$ pip install webbrowser
```

Create another file called "send.py". On it, write the following code:

```
import wasend
wasend.send("message", "phone")
```

I built this program. These are the params of the `wasend.send()` function:

```
wasend.send(message, number)
> message
    The message in plain text. (Use * for bold, _ for italic, and plain Whatsapp formatting)
    Write "\n" to make a line break.
> number
   The phone number in the format: IIINNNNNNNNN (i = indicative, n = number, without the plus sign)
```

The program takes 11.5 seconds to execute (you can change the sleep to make it fast, but give some time to WhatsApp to load. If you already have WhatsApp loaded, change line 7 in `wasend.py` to `sleep(1)`, so the program takes only 2.5 seconds to load.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in the following way, I hope it helps.

```
import requests
import json

PHONE_ID = "<whatsapp-phone-id>"
TOKEN = "<whatsapp-token>"
NUMBER = "<number>"
MESSAGE = "<message>"

URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/"+PHONE_ID+"/messages"
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer "+TOKEN, 
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
data = { 
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp", 
    "to": NUMBER, 
    "type": "text", 
    "text": json.dumps({ "preview_url": False, "body": MESSAGE}) 
}
response = requests.post(URL, headers=headers, data=data)
response_json = response.json()
print(response_json)
```

You can find more details in the following source https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/messages#text-object